# Selenium DOM is not changed after execution of Angular ng-if condition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, angular-ng-if

we have following code on page which has angular ng-if condition.

```
<p ng-if="!old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
    We have created a new account with &rsquo;{{ new_email }}&lsquo;, for you on<br> Plobal Apps to preview and test your app and mailed you the details. Please check your inbox.
</p>

<p ng-if="new_user && old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
  We have created a new account with &rsquo;{{ new_email }}&lsquo;, for you on<br> Plobal Apps to preview and test your shopify app and mailed you the details. Please check your inbox.
  <br />
  You have been logged out of the previous account with &rsquo;{{ old_email }}&lsquo;.
</p>

<p ng-if="existing_user && old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
  We have logged you in with &rsquo;{{ new_email }}&lsquo;, on Plobal Apps to preview and test your shopify app.
  <br />
  You have been logged out of the previous account with &rsquo;{{ old_email }}&lsquo;.
</p>
```

ng-if condition will execute dynamically and pickup tags as per requirements. I have observed on html page that everything is working. I observed following html code after inspecting page.

```
<!-- ngIf: !old_email -->

<!-- ngIf: new_user && old_email -->

<!-- ngIf: existing_user && old_email --><p class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="existing_user &amp;&amp; old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
  We have logged you in with ’suwarnawandhekar46@gmail.com‘, on Plobal Apps to preview and test your shopify app.
  <br>
  You have been logged out of the previous account with ’test@plobalapps.com‘.
</p><!-- end ngIf: existing_user && old_email -->
```

If I print innerHTML of parent element by selenium then  I found

```
<p ng-if="!old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
  We have created a new account with ’{{ new_email }}‘, for you on<br> Plobal Apps to preview and test your app and mailed you the details. Please check your inbox.
</p>

<p ng-if="new_user &amp;&amp; old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
  We have created a new account with ’{{ new_email }}‘, for you on<br> Plobal Apps to preview and test your shopify app and mailed you the details. Please check your inbox.
  <br>
  You have been logged out of the previous account with ’{{ old_email }}‘.
</p>

<p ng-if="existing_user &amp;&amp; old_email" style="line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;"><b>Hi,</b><br><br>
  We have logged you in with ’{{ new_email }}‘, on Plobal Apps to preview and test your shopify app.
  <br>
  You have been logged out of the previous account with ’{{ old_email }}‘.
</p>
```

As per my understanding, Selenium DOM is not changed after execution of Angular ng-if condition.
Please help me if anyone knows how to tell selenium to execute angular ng-if condition and then look for element.

Comment: You might want to consider using protractor. It is built on top of selenium and supports angular events. http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/

Comment: Do you have enough wait before getting the innerHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please recheck if the following code is really present:

```
ng-if="new_user &amp;&amp; old_email"
```

Because initially it was:

```
ng-if="new_user && old_email"
```

I.e. it looks like Selenium replaces **&&** symbols by

```
&amp;&amp;
```

in **ng-if** and it's the root of the issue: Angular can't parse "non JS" code (or interprets it incorrectly)

P.S. The same is with the following code:

```
ng-if="existing_user &amp;&amp; old_email"
```

i.e.

```
&amp;&amp;
```

is present instead of **&&** in **ng-if** too.

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply, its useful for me